# PLEASE HELP?!?! Partitioned on a Chromebook, don't know how to fix!

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, xorg, kubuntu

So I set up some hard drive partitioning on my school **Chromebook** and installed **Kubuntu** (bad idea right lol I live dangerously.)

I had it working seamlessly until an error came up when I tried to start up the OS.

I used the `sudo startkde` command which I always use in the **chrome** in-browser term.

The error code came up with something about no screens being available.

Before doing this I had just recently got Steam working and downloaded Unturned, but I had to download a bunch of stuff because all of Ubuntu software center is messed up and I did it all through terminal.

I was just wondering if anybody had any idea what is going on and how I should fix it.

Here's the error code I found.

```
[  1124.859] _XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root
[  1124.860] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[  1124.860] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1124.860] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  1124.860] Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Thu Nov 5 13:16:47 PST 2015 x86_64
[  1124.860] Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=4fa4b854-1f8d-e340-a705-e16eb78869d1/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=4fa4b854-1f8d-e340-a705-e16eb78869d1/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=0de9a59e4fc2bd5a4cbf8d55df005413c555a2ff salt=a4dffcd204bce43119840b5c2ea2fcff3e50badcb7f80eef6dddda426a663273" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=4fa4b854-1f8d-e340-a705-e16eb78869d1 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
[  1124.860] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
[  1124.860] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1124.860] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[  1124.860]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1124.860] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1124.861] (++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Tue Dec  1 21:50:25 2015
[  1124.861] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1124.861] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1124.861] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1124.861] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1124.861] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1124.861] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  1124.861] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics SNA+TearFree"
[  1124.861] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1124.861] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1124.861] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1124.861] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1124.861]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1124.861] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1124.861]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1124.861] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1124.861]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1124.861] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1124.861]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1124.861] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1124.861]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1124.861] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[  1124.861]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1124.861] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  1124.861] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1124.862] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1124.862] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fcbfe314b00
[  1124.862] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1124.862]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1124.862]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[  1124.862]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[  1124.862]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[  1124.862] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0f31:8086:0f31 rev 14, Mem @ 0xd0000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00001000/8
[  1124.862] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1124.862] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  1124.863] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[  1124.863] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1124.863]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1124.863]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1124.863]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1124.863] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[  1124.863] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  1124.863] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[  1124.864] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1124.864]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1124.864]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1124.864]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1124.864] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1124.864] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1124.864] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1124.864] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1124.864]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1124.864]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1124.864] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1124.864] (II) Loading extension GLX
[  1124.864] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  1124.865] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[  1124.865] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1124.865]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[  1124.865]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1124.865]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1124.865] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[  1124.865] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  1124.865] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[  1124.866] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1124.866]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1124.866]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1124.866] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[  1124.866] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1124.866] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[  1124.866] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1124.866]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[  1124.866]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1124.866] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[  1124.866] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  1124.867] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
[  1124.867] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[  1124.867] (II) Unloading intel
[  1124.867] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1124.867] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1124.867] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1124.867] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1124.867] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1124.867] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  1124.867] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
[  1124.867] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[  1124.867] (II) Unloading intel
[  1124.867] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1124.867] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1124.868] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[  1124.868] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  1124.868] (II) Unloading vesa
[  1124.868] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1124.868] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1124.869] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[  1124.869] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  1124.869] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  1124.869] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1124.869] (EE) No drivers available.
[  1124.869] 
Fatal server error:
[  1124.869] no screens found
[  1124.869] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at cant post that many links
 for help. 
[  1124.869] Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.
[  1124.870]
```